# Memory consumption differs by environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an MVC4 web application that, when volume is put through it, consumes ~400MB RAM in all environments excluding the production environment. When a similar volume of load is put through it on a production server (hosted externally), the memory utilisation trebles to ~1.2GB and the memory isn't released even when the application is idle. The IIS configuration across all environments is the same.

Its also worth noting that the application, when idle, releases some of that memory in my test environments, but doesn't do the same in production. The RAM gradually increases and tops out at 1.2-1.3GB, but never drops below – even if traffic is completely routed away from the server.

I have not been able to recreate this issue on any other environment other than my third party hosting platform, but before I conclusively blame the infrastructure and get the hosting company on the case I wondered:

a)  Is this a common problem and why does it happen

b)  How can I see what is using the memory

c)  Would you expect the same code to consume significantly different levels of system resources based on platform (I know my host may have monitoring etc. in production which will perhaps inflate a little)

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Do both machines (test and production) have the same amount of RAM?

Comment: Yes, both have 4GB installed

Comment: Is production environment IIS 8.5 (windows 2012 R2) ?

Comment: What is the target framework 4.5 or 4.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem which we normally face when we work on Different Environments. This is because System configuration,  Windows etc differs from system to system.

In this particular case as we see its a big difference, probably there is some loops or memory is not freed at regular intervals.

Few steps:

- Try to get root of the problem i.e. which method is taking time. Use Loggers like nlog.
- Try using profilers if you are using Sql Server
- And the third is use [ants-performance-profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Also it depends on number of user hitting on site and some deadlock conditions.
There can be numerous reasons for the same.